# passing data into d3js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a json object formatted like so

```
{
   "tweet":[

     {"text": "hello world"},
     {"text": "hello world"}

   ]
}
```

in my code below, when I print out "data" the console tells me I have an `Object tweet: Array[131]`, but when I print out my "dots" value which I'm binding my data to it says my value is `0: Array[1]`. What am I doing wrong?

```
d3.json("tweets.json", function(error, data){

  if (error) return console.warn(error);

  //tells me I have an `Object tweet: Array[131]`
  console.log(data);
  var dots = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle");

  //says I have `0: Array[1]`
  console.log(dots);
}
```

Comment: No sure how array[131] is coming. But if tweet contains array it should be within  [ ].  i. e [ {"text": "hello world"}, {"text": "hello world"} ]

Comment: In other words, what @pratikwebdev is saying is your JSON object is invalid, please review your question. After having done that, replace your console.log(data) call with console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)) and post (part of) the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments mention, fix your JSON like provided below. I like to use a JSON validator (like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to confirm I have valid JSON data. Also, need to make a few changes in your Javascript. Please see updated Javascript code also below.

JSON file

```
{
   "tweet":[
      {"text":"hello world"},
      {"text":"hello world"}
   ]
}
```

Javascript file

```
d3.json("tweetsTest.json", function (error, data) {

    if (error) return console.warn(error);

    //tells me I have an `Object tweet: Array[131]`
    console.log(data);
    var dots = d3.select("svg")//modified so d3.select("svg") not just svg
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data.tweet)//modified, need data.tweet to access because you have root "tweet"
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)//added r, cx, and cy
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
            return (i+1) * 20;
        })//added
        .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
            return 20;
        });//added

    //says I have `0: Array[1]`
    console.log(dots);
});
```

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3_stackoverflow34456619.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <svg style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px lightgray solid;"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```